# How can I sum a row's value in my table based on a specific type?

Tags: sql

My table looks like this. Its a table with an inventory of clothes.

Basically, an user can enter a type of clothe and a quantity.
When he did it, it add a new value in the table with the date of the input.

[image: | Name | Type | Quantity | Date | |-------|------|----------|------------| | Paul | 2 | 1 | 01.01.2020 | | Louis | 3 | 2 | 20.01.2020 | | Paul | 3 | 5 | 14.02.2020 | | Paul | 2 | 2 | 16.03.2020 |]

The `type` 2 is for shoes and the `type` 3 for shirts

What I'm trying to do is to `sum` the `quantity` based on the `type` like this :

[image: | Name | Shirts | Shoes | |-------|--------|-------| | Paul | 5 | 3 | | Louis | 2 | 0 |]

So I tried this :

```
SELECT name, type, sum(quantity)
from Clothes
where type="2"
group by name
```

But it didn't work, it sums all the type of clothes. How can I do ?

Comment: Please tag with db platform.  What is the data type of type column?

Comment: You say "it didn't work". In what way? Did you get an error message? If you got a result, how did it differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(case when type = 3 then quantity else 0 end) shirts,
       SUM(case when type = 2 then quantity else 0 end) shoes
from Clothes
group by name
```

Comment: My bad. I had a `where` that was filtering the values. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should group using the type too.
Doing this you'll get a table with 3 columns:
1st one with the name, secondo col with the type and the third with the quantity

```
SELECT name, type, sum(quantity)
from Clothes
group by name,type
```

[image]

Then you should format as you wish the data

If otherwise you want to get the exact result with a query you should dig more deep and maybe using some 'Case' inside the sum function and put a zero if is not of the selected type:

```
select name, 
sum(case when type = 3 then quantity else 0 end) as Shirts,
sum(case when type = 2 then quantity else 0 end) as Shoes
from Clothes
group by name;
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a PIVOT table will achieve the same result with multi-column aggregation of quantities corresponding to the type column:

```
SELECT [ProductName], [2] As Shoes, [3] As Clothes
FROM 
(SELECT [ProductName], [ProductType], [Quantity] FROM [Inventory_Table])
AS DataSource
PIVOT 
(SUM([Quantity]) FOR [ProductType] IN ([2], [3])) AS pvt_table
```

Note: For the above to work in SQL Server T-SQL I had to replace the [Name] and [Type] columns with other columns names.